# Get custom attribute from select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, attributes

How can I get `data-itemslimit` attribute from selected option?

```js
$(function() {
    $('#content_id').on('change', function(){
      alert($('#content_id').attr('data-itemslimit'));
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="content_id" class="form-control" data-reactid=".2.3.4.2.0.1.0.1.0">
  <option value="22" data-itemslimit="9" data-reactid=".2.3.4.2.0.1.0.1.0.$22">Content Test</option>
  <option value="23" data-itemslimit="6" data-reactid=".2.3.4.2.0.1.0.1.0.$23">Second Content</option>
</select>
```

I get `undefined`...

Comment: $('option:selected',this).attr('data-itemslimit')

Comment: What makes you think it *has* this attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `option:selected`

```js
$(function() {
    $('#content_id').on('change', function(){
      alert($('option:selected', this).attr('data-itemslimit'));
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="content_id" class="form-control" data-reactid=".2.3.4.2.0.1.0.1.0">
  <option value="22" data-itemslimit="9" data-reactid=".2.3.4.2.0.1.0.1.0.$22">Content Test</option>
  <option value="23" data-itemslimit="6" data-reactid=".2.3.4.2.0.1.0.1.0.$23">Second Content</option>
</select>
```

**Reference**

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#selector-context

https://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `$('option:selected',this).attr('data-itemslimit')` because it's your options that has the `data-itemslimit` not the select itself.

**Demo**

```js
$(function() {
    $('#content_id').on('change', function(){
      alert($('option:selected',this).attr('data-itemslimit'));
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="content_id" class="form-control" data-reactid=".2.3.4.2.0.1.0.1.0">
  <option value="22" data-itemslimit="9" data-reactid=".2.3.4.2.0.1.0.1.0.$22">Content Test</option>
  <option value="23" data-itemslimit="6" data-reactid=".2.3.4.2.0.1.0.1.0.$23">Second Content</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below code.

```
$('#content_id').on('change', function(e) {
        var data = $(this).children("option:selected").data('itemslimit');
        alert(data);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Option:selected for change:

js:

```
$(function() {
     $('select').on('change', function(){
      alert($('option:selected',this).attr('data-itemslimit'));
    })
});
```

html:

```
<select id="content_id" class="form-control" data-reactid=".2.3.4.2.0.1.0.1.0">
  <option value="22" data-itemslimit="9" data-reactid=".2.3.4.2.0.1.0.1.0.$22">Content Test</option>
  <option value="23" data-itemslimit="6" data-reactid=".2.3.4.2.0.1.0.1.0.$23">Second Content</option>
</select>
```